# Cannot distribute in-house iOS App "Cannot Open Page" Error iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, ios7

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://app.company.com/myapp/app.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.company.*</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0.0 (1.0.0)</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Conference APp</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I am trying to access manifest file, to download the App on iPhone.

I point it to the manifest file but it does not seems to read it on the iOS device:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=main.com/manifest.plist">Download </a>
```

Comment: How are you "pointing" to the manifest file?

Comment: <article>
  
  <ul class="roundRectangle box">
   <li style="text-align:center"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https://main.com/manifest.plist">Download ProjectA Reports</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <p class="white-text" style="text-align:center">ProjectA Reports by Tech Special Projects!</p>
 
 </article>

Comment: I edited your question to include your HTML code, next time please just do it that way instead of posting a comment. :-)

Comment: I really appreciate it looks much better now!

Answer (score 0):

The `url` parameter of the itms-services link needs to be properly escaped (you can't use a / character, has to be %2f) and it needs to be an absolute URL instead of a relative URL.

Try changing it to:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fapp%2fmanifest.plist">Download ProjectA Reports</a>
```

Comment: Hey this still does not seem to work, anything else I can try?

Comment: Try comparing your manifest to one that works? Eg compare your code to TestFlight's code.

Comment: I had one working on ios6, that's the one that I am using and it's still not working

Comment: THIS IS FOR SURE NOT THE WAY TO GO ABOUT IT.

Answer (score 0):

The path was incorrect. There's not difference between this file for IOS6 and IOS7